# Compare Two NSDate's by day

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I have two `NSDate` objects, `dateOne` and `dateTwo`. If `dateTwo` is later than `dateone` but on the same day as `dateOne` (ex. January 1, 2015 4:00pm and January 1, 2015 5:00pm) then I want to return that they are the same. However, as soon as `dateTwo` is on the next day or later (ex. January 1, 2015 and January 2, 2015), I want to return that `dateOne` < `dateTwo`.

I'm currently trying to accomplish this by doing:

```
- (BOOL)dateTwoLaterThanDateOne:(NSDate *)dateOne withDateTwo:(NSDate *)dateTwo {
    if([dateTwo compare: dateOne] == NSOrderedDescending) // if dateTwo is later in time than dateOne
    {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561554/cocoa-touch-how-do-i-see-if-two-nsdates-are-in-the-same-day, it should pretty much list all options.

Answer (score 1):

Check if it's the same day with NSDateComponents.

And if it's not compare them to see if they ascend or decend.

```
- (BOOL)dateTwoLaterThanDateOne:(NSDate *)dateOne withDateTwo:(NSDate *)dateTwo
{
    NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    unsigned unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay;
    NSDateComponents* comp1 = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:dateOne];
    NSDateComponents* comp2 = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:dateTwo];
    BOOL sameDay = [comp1 day]  == [comp2 day] && [comp1 month] == [comp2 month] && [comp1 year]  == [comp2 year] ;

   return sameDay ? !sameDay : ([dateOne compare:dateTwo] == NSOrderedAscending);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the day component from each and compare them. Something like:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSInteger day = [components day];
```

Do that for both dates and then do the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code..

```
NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [dateTwo timeIntervalSinceDate: dateOne]; 
int numberOfDays = secondsBetween /(3600*24);

if (numberOfDays == 0) {
        NSLog(@"same day"); //dateOne = dateTwo
}else if (numberOfDays>0){
        NSLog(@"two > one"); //dateOne > dateTwo
}else if (numberOfDays<0){
        NSLog(@"two < one"); //dateOne < dateTwo
}
```

This code helps you :)