# Compare NSDates without time component in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I'm trying to compare NSDates. Basically, i want to know if both are same or not. i've googled it and found some solutions but they are applicable for iOS8+

What i'm doing right now is:

```
 func isCurrentDate() -> Bool
{
    let currentDate = NSDate()

    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        let order = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().compareDate(currentDate, toDate: self,
            toUnitGranularity: .Day)

        if order == .OrderedSame {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false    //This part need to be updated
}
```

i can do this by comparing date formatted strings "YYYY MM DD" (as following code), but i feel that it's not correct approach.

```
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY MM DD"

    if dateFormatter.stringFromDate(currentDate) == dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self) {
        return true
    }
```

i've checked a few posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561554/cocoa-touch-how-do-i-see-if-two-nsdates-are-in-the-same-day) but it's in objective-c and i'm finding it difficult to translate the syntax for swift

Comment: So you want code that works with iOS versions older than 8.0?

Comment: Have you looked at using `CFDate`?

Comment: @Duncan C, yes i am targeting ios7 as well,

Comment: @JAL, the post you're referring is in objective-c and i'm not getting the format. + i've not checked CFDate. i'll do that

Comment: Use `NSCalendar().currentCalendar().isDate(currentDate, equalToDate : dateToCompare, toUnitGranularity : .Day)`

Comment: @FayzaNawaz for iOS7 you can compare the date description check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27752705/2303865

Comment: @FayzaNawaz comparing the date as string it is not a problem but YYYY it is only used for WeekOfYear you need to use yyyy (lowercase)